# Auto Hide Angular Ngx Spinner if API Throws Error

Tags: angular, typescript, spinner, ngx-spinner

I am using Metronic (Angular) theme. I write spinner.show() before calling API. After the API code, I write spinner.hide(). But if an error message is returned from the API service, the error popup stays behind the spinner. How can I hide the spinner automatically if the API service throws an error?

Comment: Pipe in a [`finalize`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize) operator to the API call and hide the spinner within it's callback. `finalize` is triggered for both `error` and `complete` notifications.

Comment: And here was me coming to answer with a `catchError` block ^^ ruth's answer is more elegant as it avoids repeating code. I didn't know that finalize was also called on error!

Answer (score 0):

You will never predict when the finalize is executed I'd would advice you stay away form it.

```
     this._sessionService.getCurrentLoginInformations()
    .subscribe((sessionInfo: GetCurrentLoginInformationsOutput) => {
      if (this.isAdmin(sessionInfo.roles)) {
        this.dashboardName = DashboardCustomizationConst.dashboardNames.defaultTenantDashboard;
      } else {
        this.dashboardName = DashboardCustomizationConst.dashboardNames.defaultTenantUserDashboard;
      }
      this.loading=true; 
this.hide();
    },
    (err) => { 
this.hide();
    });

hide() {
this.spinner.hide();
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. I tried the code you wrote, but the spinner still does not close.

Comment: share the code in `this.spinner.hide()` method